# .net Memory leak problem

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, memory-management

I have an application in .net that gets more and more memory.
I've got some analyzes from a team member about the most common and most heavy instances that my application allocates.

[image]

The problem is that I don't know what to do next.
The source code is huge!!
and I need best practice how to capture the problematic functions/lines of code.

p.s - I've tried using visual studio's ".net memory allocation (sampling)" feature but it always failed to create the report. (guess it could be another question).

Comment: BTW, which version fo Visual Studio are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Visual Studio Profiler` perfectly suit your requirements, it able to show a **hot path** in the call stack. You've to learn how to work with profiler so if you can't generate Visual Studio profiler report and was not able to investigate how to do it - it worth start reading documentation first because no matter which tools you are using in this case.

Below are useful links regarding Visual Studio profiler:

- [Visual Studio Profiler Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/)
- [What code path is allocating the most bytes for a type?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2008/06/14/where-are-the-most-bytes-for-a-type-being-allocated.aspx)
- [Pinpoint a performance issue using hotpath in Visual Studio 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ianhu/archive/2007/09/14/pinpoint-a-performance-issue-using-hotpath-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx)

**EDIT: Hot Path By VS Profiler:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple thing that I like doing first is to use windbg with psscor2. 
Then i do a !gcroot and/or !GCRef. This *sometimes* gives insight into the base references that keep the objects alive.

Sorry for that rushed answer, check out for example [this blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2010/08/26/psscor2-gc-heap-analysis-commands.aspx) for some more references if you don't know about psscor2

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken it looks like your teammate is already using WinDbg with a managed extension (maybe SOS?) and have called **!dumpheap -stat**. Get a copy of his memory dump file, open in it in WinDbg, and load SOS.

The first step is to drill down to the particular types. In your case, it looks like you have an unusually large allocation for strings (around 84MB). So try looking at the list of strings by running:

```
!dumpheap -type System.String
```

It will output a **long** list of string instances. The output will look something like this:

```
Address    MT           Size  Gen
0x412d0030 0x79b94638   812   1    System.String XXXX
0x422d0030 0x79b94638   812   1    System.String XXXX
0x432d0030 0x79b94638   812   1    System.String XXXX
```

This command will probably run for a few minutes because you have a lot of string instances but try to observe the output while its running. If you notice that a lot of the instances have the same size, that's usually a good sign that you are not properly releasing your resources. Any of those instances is a good candidate for the next step. If at the end of the list you also see strings with large sizes, these are good candidates for the next step as well.

The next step is to check which objects are referencing a particular string instance and is preventing it from being garbage-collected. You can do this by using an address from the **dumpheap** output above and then calling:

```
!gcroot 0x432d0030
```

This will output something like this:

```
173866dc(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection)->
173866ec(System.Collections.ArrayList)->
173894b8(System.Object[])->
17386d0c(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem)->
17386ce8(System.String)
```

You can read that from bottom to top. So in this example, the *String* is held by *ListItem* which in turn is held by an array of *Objects*. At this point, solving your problem becomes more of an art. Start from the bottom of that chain (including *String*) and for each line going up, check if you can justify storing that object in memory. If not, then you should find a way to release that resource and have it garbage collected. This step will most likely require you to look and analyse the code for each class.

Tip: Since you also have an unusually large number of instances for System.Action, there is a good chance that you are subscribing to an event/multicast delegate and you forgot to unsubscribe afterwards.